# Can waste heat in specific environments be collected into photons and converted to electricity?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, non-linear-optics, solar-cells, thermoelectricity

<sub>[Crossposted](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/42463/) on Engineering SE</sub>

---

[Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/219353/289358) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/572898/289358) show possibility to combine photons of lower energy to one higher. Thinking of an application, it could be used to dissipate heat from laptop. Liquid cooling device collect the heat from heat sink. Then the device makes infrared photons with the heat and send photons to an "upconversion" device. This device combine infrared into visible light photons and shine onto conventional solar cell.

One would think why not using thermoelectric generator which still needs to dissipate heat; however, *by imagination* could "upconversion" package *waste heat* collected using waste heat and turn them into light? My sentences may appear rudimentary as they are just ideas.

Comment: What you're suggesting is similar to placing photovoltaic cells (instead of human eyes) at the end of [night-vision goggles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night-vision_device). Would you agree?

Comment: Try to come up with the **simplest** experiment you can think of. Second harmonic generation in nonlinear crystals can halve the wavelength and convert 1000 nm (infrared) light into 500 nm (visible greenish) light, which is why everything is green when one wears (some) night-vision goggles.